# Open-source platform for code collaboration that I can put on my server?

Tags: software-development, open-source, web-development, web-services, code-review

I need an open-source platform I can put on my server where code can be collaboratively revised. It should be possible to transfer files directly to the platform. What are my options? I'd like something that is lightweight. Smartbear Code Collaborator seems good, but I need it to be free. What are my alternatives?

Comment: You mean something like [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/)?

Comment: @Undo It looks great but unfortunately I don't have SSH access to my server, which I believe means I can't install it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at RhodeCode